# Unable to access University Website using eduroam

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I'm unable to access gold.ac.uk (158.223.1.87) using the Campus WI-FI (eduroam)

I've tried using my Macbook Air with Chrome, Safari and Firefox
I've also dual booted to a Windows 8 machine and used IE and Firefox, with the same results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted the administrators of the website to verify the website is currently functional?  Have you confirmed the address of the website should be 158.223.1.87?  Have you triend a different DNS provider to verify, the problem isn't caused by your current DNS provider, being unable to resolve the domain?

Comment: Speak to your campus IT support.